# Please Tell me how to increase the brightness of MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone

i do r&d but i didn't get anywhere how to increase or decrease brightness of mpmovieplayercontroller i have found in ALPlaycontroller it is a custom player but i don't want in this so please tell me there is any way to increase or decrease the brightness of mpmovieplayercontroller in IOS

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the brightness of the movie player, it follows the device screen brightness.

You'll have to change the brightness of the movie either by editing it before serving it, or by building a custom player that uses `CIFilter` to adjust brightness of the frames as they arrive.